# jquery textarea autocomplete does not show after clearing it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Something really weird is happening with my code:
I am using jQuery autocomplete to fill out an equipment form and send it via ajax. Since you can enter multiple equipment items without refreshing the browser, I clear all fields when the dialog with the form opens. Unfortunately the textarea field is cleared, but does not autocomplete. What is throwing me off is the fact that if I inspect the textarea it shows as filled (see picture). 
[image]
It actually works if I comment the $( "#text").val(''); line (of course, the field does not reset). No errors are shown.
What could be causing this behavior?
As lean as possible, here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var equipment = [

              {
                id: "",
                label: "",
                text: "",
                category: "",
                rev_type: "",
                price: "",
                cost: "",
                time: ""
              },
            {
            id: "1",
            label: "Delete",
            text: "",
            category: "4",
            rev_type: "1",
            price: "0.00",
            cost: "0",
            time: "0"
            },
            {
            id: "32",
            label: "Samsung 55\" LED Monitor",
            text: "",
            category: "3",
            rev_type: "1",
            price: "650.00",
            cost: "150",
            time: "60"
            },
            {
            id: "31",
            label: "ART Audio DI",
            text: "",
            category: "4",
            rev_type: "1",
            price: "55.00",
            cost: "0",
            time: "0"
            },
            {
            id: "30",
            label: "Whirlwind PC Stereo DI",
            text: "",
            category: "4",
            rev_type: "1",
            price: "55.00",
            cost: "0",
            time: "0"
            }
];
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        updateTotal();

        function clearForm() {
            // clean fields
            $( "#text").val('');
            return false;
        }

        $( document).on( 'click', '.add_edit_equipment', function(){
           clearForm();
           /* ***** Dialog ***** */
        });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").on("focus", ".equipment", function() {
    $( this ).autocomplete({
        source: equipment,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#add_edit_form #equipment" ).val( $(this).html(ui.item.label).text() );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#text" ).html( ui.item.text ).text();
            itemSubTotal();
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

The field giving me issues:

```
<textarea id="text" class="form-control" name="text" cols="55" rows="5" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
```

ANSWER: I still don't know why it stopped working and gave me this issue, but it started to work again when I replaced the following line

```
$( "#text" ).html( ui.item.text ).text();
```

with

```
$( "#text" ).val( ui.item.text );
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Which code is used to fill this text area ? could you please post fiddle link if possible ?

Comment: It is the line $( "#add_edit_form #text" ).html( ui.item.text ).text(); the one that fills the text area. I will try to make a fiddle soon. Thanks!

Comment: could you please add **equipment** content ?

Comment: added example equipment variable

Comment: Your code does not get compile and you have not posted the html contents

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

Reference http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<textarea id="text" class="form-control" name="text" cols="55" rows="5" placeholder="Description"></textarea> <br/>
<input type="text" class="equipment" placeholder="Enter text to search"/>
<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear"/>
<input type="button" id="fill" value="Fill"/>


<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clear").click(function(){
   $( "#text" ).html( "" ); 
  });
  $("#fill").click(function(){
   $( "#text" ).html( "X" ); 
  });
 
   var equipment = [
    "ActionScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
 
  
  $( ".equipment" ).autocomplete({
   source: equipment,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#text" ).html( ui.item.label);
    return true;
   }
  });
  
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low-quality on SO.  While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.